# iText 7.0.2 Destination error

Tags: java, itext

I am learning how to generate pdfs using java code but it seems I can't seem to understand why this error is appearing.

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream("D:/t.pdf"));
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document doc = new Document(pdf);
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
doc.close();
```

When I try to state a destination folder to output the pdf file to, it constantly shows me an error as shown below. I am not sure why it is doing this. Please provide me with some guidance on how to resolve this. I tried to also not use FileOutputStream and just use the string location instead but it shows the same error.

> wait.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
>       at com.itextpdf.io.font.FontRegisterProvider.(FontRegisterProvider.java:65)
>       at com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory.(FontProgramFactory.java:61)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:215)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:201)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:143)
>       at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:92)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.getDefaultProperty(RootElement.java:180)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.getProperty(AbstractRenderer.java:289)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.getProperty(AbstractRenderer.java:282)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.getProperty(AbstractRenderer.java:282)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.getProperty(AbstractRenderer.java:282)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.resolveFonts(TextRenderer.java:1045)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.resolveChildrenFonts(LineRenderer.java:706)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.layout(LineRenderer.java:94)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.layout(ParagraphRenderer.java:171)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:111)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:108)
>       at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:143)
>       at report.GenerateReport.GeneratePDF(GenerateReport.java:136)
>       at report.GenerateReport.main(GenerateReport.java:87)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 20 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

The error message states that it cannot find the *simple logging facade for Java* `LoggerFactory` class.

I.e. you did not add all required JAR files to your code. In particular you seem to have missed the **slf4j-api.jar**.

Comment: To add onto mkl's answer: do you use Maven or Gradle? Because if you do, all required jars are automatically added.

Comment: Thank you so much! Issue solved after adding in slf4j-api and simple jar files.